# Can you apply an Angular themes primary color to a div?

Tags: css, angular, sass, theming

Is there a way to theme an Angular 7 application, so that you can:

- Apply theming to normal HTML elements too and not just Angular Material components
- Switch the theme at runtime
- Don't have to use a class for every color and every type of usage (`color`, `background-color`, `border-color`, ...), like in some other questions and solutions.

### For Example

I want to do something like this:

```
<div color="primary">

</div>
```

But that does not work, because the `color` attribute is only for angular material components.

Also, I want to be able to change the background color, text color, and so on, depending on the current theme. (Dark theme, Light theme)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

### About the solution

With this solution you can:

- Switch the theme during runtime
- Get the current theme during runtime
- Theme directly in CSS without the usage of extra classes or anything
- Have an easy to use and easy to understand solution, that only requires a one time setup

Cons:

- Uses CSS variables. Some older browsers might not support them
- Relies on newer Angular versions. I don't know if this would work in older versions (Tested in Angular 6 & 7)

This is what I am using in my project right now:

### Setup

First you need to define a theme.

Here is an example called `dark-theme.scss` located in `src/themes`:

```
@import '~@angular/material/theming';
@include mat-core();

// Set variables to whatever colors you want for your app
$dark-theme-primary: mat-palette($mat-pink);
$dark-theme-accent: mat-palette($mat-light-blue);
$dark-theme-warn: mat-palette($mat-red);

$dark-theme: mat-dark-theme(
    $dark-theme-primary,
    $dark-theme-accent,
    $dark-theme-warn
);

@include angular-material-theme($dark-theme);
```

Then you need a SCSS function that can create theme SCSS and CSS variables:

Here is mine called `functions.scss` in `src/assets/scss`:

```
@mixin generate-theme-vars($theme) {
  //default palette foreground/background:
  $foreground-palette: map-get($theme, foreground);
  $background-palette: map-get($theme, background);

  /////////////////////////////////////////////////
  // SCSS VARS
  /////////////////////////////////////////////////

  $primary: mat-color(map-get($theme, primary));
  $accent: mat-color(map-get($theme, accent));
  $warn: mat-color(map-get($theme, warn));

  $base: mat-color($foreground-palette, base);
  $divider: mat-color($foreground-palette, divider);
  $dividers: mat-color($foreground-palette, dividers);
  $disabled: mat-color($foreground-palette, disabled);
  $disabled-button: mat-color($foreground-palette, disabled-button);
  $disabled-text: mat-color($foreground-palette, disabled-text);
  $hint-text: mat-color($foreground-palette, hint-text);
  $secondary-text: mat-color($foreground-palette, secondary-text);
  $icon: mat-color($foreground-palette, icon);
  $icons: mat-color($foreground-palette, icons);
  $text: mat-color($foreground-palette, text);
  $slider-off: mat-color($foreground-palette, slider-off);
  $slider-off-active: mat-color($foreground-palette, slider-off-active);
  
  $status-bar: mat-color($background-palette, status-bar);
  $app-bar: mat-color($background-palette, app-bar);
  $background: mat-color($background-palette, background);
  $hover: mat-color($background-palette, hover);
  $card: mat-color($background-palette, card);
  $dialog: mat-color($background-palette, dialog);
  $disabled-button: mat-color($background-palette, disabled-button);
  $raised-button: mat-color($background-palette, raised-button);
  $focused-button: mat-color($background-palette, focused-button);
  $selected-button: mat-color($background-palette, selected-button);
  $selected-disabled-button: mat-color($background-palette, selected-disabled-button);
  $disabled-button-toggle: mat-color($background-palette, disabled-button-toggle);

  /////////////////////////////////////////////////
  // CSS VARS
  /////////////////////////////////////////////////


  --primary-color: #{$primary};
  --accent-color: #{$accent};
  --warn-color: #{$warn};

  --base-color: #{$base};
  --divider-color: #{$divider};
  --dividers-color: #{$dividers};
  --disabled-color: #{$disabled};
  --disabled-text-color: #{$disabled-text};
  --hint-text-color: #{$hint-text};
  --secondary-text-color: #{$secondary-text};
  --icon-color: #{$icon};
  --icons-color: #{$icons};
  --text-color: #{$text};
  --slider-off-color: #{$slider-off};
  --slider-off-active-color: #{$slider-off-active};

  --status-bar-color: #{$status-bar};
  --app-bar-color: #{$app-bar};
  --background-color: #{$background};
  --hover-color: #{$hover};
  --card-color: #{$card};
  --dialog-color: #{$dialog};
  --disabled-button-color: #{$disabled-button};
  --raised-button-color: #{$raised-button};
  --focused-button-color: #{$focused-button};
  --selected-button-color: #{$selected-button};
  --selected-disabled-button-color: #{$selected-disabled-button};
  --disabled-button-toggle-color: #{$disabled-button-toggle};
}
```

After that, you are all set and all you have to do is to create a class for every theme in your global `styles.scss`:

```
@import "functions";
@import "~@angular/material/theming";

// You have to define one of those for every theme you offer
.dark-theme {
    @import "themes/dark-theme";
    @include angular-material-theme($dark-theme);
    @include generate-theme-vars($dark-theme);
}

.light-theme {
    @import "themes/light-theme";
    @include angular-material-theme($light-theme);
    @include generate-theme-vars($light-theme);
}
```

### Usage

To apply the theme you want to use, you need to put the CSS class `dark-theme` (or whatever you called it) to an element that contains all other elements.

I put it to the HTML tag:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en" class="dark-theme">
    <!-- ... -->
</html>
```

Now you can switch the theme on runtime, by changing that class with JavaScript to `light-theme` for example.

In every CSS property that wants a color, you can use variables now:

```
div {
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;

    background-color: var(--app-bar-color);

    .someText {
        color: var(--text-color);
    }
}
```

If you want to do something in your CSS if a special theme is applied and the change is not the color itself, then do it like this:

```
// Example: We want to remove some div only when the light-theme is used
div {
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;

    background-color: var(--app-bar-color);

    
    :host-context(.light-theme) & {
        display: none;
    }
}
```

### PS

For everyone who might wonder why I am using `@import "functions";`, even though they are in different folders:

Go into `angular.json` and add to the object `projects > <YourProject> > architect > build > options` the following:

```
"stylePreprocessorOptions": {
    "includePaths": [
    "src/assets/scss"
    ]
},
```

Now you can use `@import "functions";` from every path.

### In case you need to support IE (untested, might need work)

So if you can't use CSS variables on some clients, you can define a fallback for the specified colors like so:

```
div {
    background-color: red; // fallback to red if the variable doesnt exist -> Old browsers, or IE
    background-color: var(--app-bar-color);
}
```

With this knowledge, you could for example define a few SCSS variables in `styles.scss`:

```
@import "functions";
@import "~@angular/material/theming";

// Default theme
@import "themes/dark-theme";
@include angular-material-theme($dark-theme);

// Generate SCSS vars
$foreground-palette: map-get($theme, foreground);
$background-palette: map-get($theme, background);

/////////////////////////////////////////////////
// SCSS VARS
/////////////////////////////////////////////////

$primary: mat-color(map-get($theme, primary));
$accent: mat-color(map-get($theme, accent));
$warn: mat-color(map-get($theme, warn));

// ... and all the other vars from above if you would like


// You have to define one of those for every theme you offer
.dark-theme {
    // Only init the CSS vars here, because the rest is in default
    @include generate-theme-vars($dark-theme);
}

.light-theme {
    @import "themes/light-theme";
    @include angular-material-theme($light-theme);
    @include generate-theme-vars($light-theme);
}
```

Now you could use it like this:

```
div {
    background-color: $primary; // fallback
    background-color: var(--primary-color);
}
```

> This cant be changed dynamically with JS during the runtime anymore
> though!!

Comment: This totally looks like a great solution. However: I am not able to use it: `@include angular-material-theme($dark-theme);` (at `styles.scss`, the same as the one in your response). Do you happen to know why I am getting this?

Comment: Works quite well. CSS variables browser support might be the largest downside.

Comment: @Igor sorry to answer so late - I dont know why it is not working. maybe you can send me an error? alternatively I can send you a repo where I used the above code.

Comment: @Dschuli Yeah according to caniuse it is supported for 95% of all current users, but I guess it depends on what you are doing. Some tech heavy stuff -> I expect people to upgrade their browser. An online magazine for old people -> yeah better not use it there I guess.

Comment: @MauriceNino I think I got it work - so it's resolved. I don't have a CodePen example, but I think it was my fault, because apparently the error now went away. Thank you though - your question and answer really helped!

Comment: @Dschuli I have added a section to support browsers without CSS variables, but I haven't tested it yet though. Might be an idea on how to combat this problem if it is from importance.

Answer (score 0):

For those who might be getting the error - `SassError: Undefined variable.`,if you are trying to use any of the variables defined under `@mixin generate-theme-vars($theme)`, you need to add `!global` in those variables. For instance define:
`$base: mat-color($foreground-palette, base) !global;`

This will make the variables global and you can use it anywhere.

Comment: You should use the CSS variables though (and not the SASS ones), or am I understanding something wrong?

Comment: I see your point. SASS ones will change with as per the theme that is written last in `style.scss`. Thanks for the question !!